# some scenes crash when trying to load them on mobile, Unity C# (AR game)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

In the Unity editor, every scene loads smoothly, no errors in the console. But once built and running on an android device (OnePlus3 and Galaxy A50), just 2 specific scenes make the whole app/game crash.

I checked on the profiler if my assets were heavy in case it uses a lot of memory but that wasn't the case.

```
public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] Transform[] enableOnStart;
[SerializeField] Image fade;
[SerializeField] float fadeTime;
[SerializeField] PoiController poiController;

void Awake() {
    if(poiController != null)
        poiController.OnInitializationFinished += OnInitialized;
    else
        StartCoroutine(StartScene());
}

void OnDisable() {
    if(poiController != null)
        poiController.OnInitializationFinished -= OnInitialized;
}

void OnInitialized() {
    StartCoroutine(StartScene());
}

public void GoToScene(string sceneName) {
    StartCoroutine(EndScene(sceneName));
}

public void GoToScene(int sceneIndex)
{
    StartCoroutine(EndScene(sceneIndex));
}

public void GoToScene(string sceneName, float delay) {
    StartCoroutine(EndScene(sceneName, delay));
}

IEnumerator StartScene() {
    if(fade != null) {
        yield return StartCoroutine(Fade(true));
    }

    foreach(Transform transform in enableOnStart) {
        transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    yield return 0;
}

IEnumerator EndScene(string sceneName) {
    yield return StartCoroutine(Fade(false));

    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
}

IEnumerator EndScene(int sceneIndex)
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(Fade(false));

    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
}

IEnumerator EndScene(string sceneName, float delay) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    StartCoroutine(EndScene(sceneName));
}

IEnumerator Fade(bool isIn) {
    fade.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    float timer = 0, start, end;
    if(isIn) {
        start = 1;
        end = 0;
    } else {
        start = 0;
        end = 1;
    }

    while(timer / fadeTime < 1) {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        Color color = fade.color;
        color.a = Mathf.Lerp(start, end, timer / fadeTime);

        fade.color = color;

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

}

Here's the link for logcat crash logs:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IH1hJuSU-HL-nEsT9e5qms5JUIJRPIGV?usp=sharing

Comment: How much memory usage does the Profiler show? Are you using default Texture compression settings or using a specific compression setting like ASTC? Most importantly, what do [logcat crash logs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@1.2/manual/index.html) say?

Comment: @yasirkula for the memory usage, it was about 500-600 Mb and for the texture, I put "don't override" as for the compression method it's LZ4. Also I updates my post, so that you can check the logcat crash

Comment: The JPEG compression have made the red text very hard to read. I wish you had uploaded it as PNG... Regardless, you can see that the latest stack trace entry points to a Unity Ads function. The crash is very likely caused by Unity Ads. I'd recommend you to report the crash to the Unity Ads team.